# Using a pointer to data member as a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to know the rationale for preventing pointers to data members from being used as non-type template arguments, as explained in [temp.arg.nontype]:

> [Note: The address of an array element or non-static data member is not an 
>   acceptable template-argument. [snip] — end note ]

Furthermore, cppreference.com [says that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments) pointers to data-members **can** be used as non-type template arguments, but they are required to be expressed as `&Class::member`. This seems to be confirmed by the following code (checked
on both Clang and GCC):

```
#include <type_traits>
struct Foo { int bar; };
using X = std::integral_constant<int Foo::*, &Foo::bar>; // works
using Y = std::integral_constant<int Foo::*, X::value>; // fails
```

Hence, I would like to know whether I missed something in the standard or cppreference.com is wrong on this point. If cppreference.com is right, is there any rationale for allowing `&Foo::bar` but not `X::value`?

I'm using the [C++14 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that current gcc accepts it, and clang does too, because http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html has been implemented by both. That is, of course, if you use their C++17 modes.

Comment: Current meaning trunk? Because 5.3.0 does not accept in in C++1z mode: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bd0dfdbe29e9fb2)

Comment: Yes, current meaning trunk.

Comment: Ville is correct; GCC and Clang trunk accept the code I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know the rationale for preventing pointers to data members from being used as non-type template arguments [...]

I do not believe it says that.

> [Note: The **address of** an array element or non-static data member is not an acceptable template-argument. [snip] — end note ]

Now, maybe I'm reading to much into the wording of this note,
but I see a distinction between *address of* (i.e. `&s.s -> int*`) and pointer to member (i.e. `&S::s -> int S::* -> int*`), which *is* allowed.

If you expand that `[snip]` you'll see that note answers part of your question already:

```
X<&s.s> x5;  // error: &S::s must be used
X<&S::s> x6; // OK: address of static member
```

So cppreference is not wrong.

Comment: The example you expanded does not say `// error: &S::s must be used`, but rather `// error: address of non-static member`. However, I do agree that your interpretation makes much sense, and hence cppreference is probably right. Would you happen to know the rationale for requiring pointers to non-static data members to be expressed as `&Class::Member` in order to be passable as non-type template arguments?

Comment: I just asked the question on [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/5QNDgH3G4BA/discussion).

Comment: @LouisDionne oh, I was quoting N4140, you were using N4296

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thanks for the help, still!